# Reset InputStream on file upload in Java

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i have a problem with InputStream processing. I have SpringMVC project with file upload. File is plain text file. I want first to be sure of character encoding so I use stream to detect charset encoding. And then according to this encoding i try to read file. My problem is when I am detecting the charset InputStream pointer is moved forward so when i try to read file after, it skips the beginning of file.

I think i can add read bytes to some list than read this list first and continue with stream, but i don't want to end up with entire file in memory.

How can I start stream from the beginning in file upload?

Answer (score 2):

XY problem. You don't need the character encoding. Just copy the incoming data using streams, instead of `Readers` and `Writers`. That way, whatever the encoding is, it's preserved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, The problem is i don't want to preserve encoding. I am generating pdf with user uploaded data. Pdf is generated in utf-8 but users upload files with local encoding. So i wanted to detect encoding first. Because should convert them to utf-8 format.

Answer (score 0):

You can't restart stream once you read some data, and this is feature of streams.
You can use any Reader class you like, for example

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, charset));
```

If you don't know charset in advance and it may differ from default, you would better save stream content to in-memory structure or file and then analyze it.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using in-memory. I saved read data (until detection) in byte array, then combined them into one stream with SequenceInputStream(byteArrayStream, originalStream) and than used buffered reader. I hope it wouldn't blow up the memory.